# Building a library GLFW using Clang

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw, clang++

please tell me how I can build a GLFW library 64-bit using Clang C++ on Windows 10?

I already build it with the help of MinGW and CMake, but for Clang I did not find instructions.

Comment: It shouldn't be any different, just set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` accordingly.

Comment: @arrowd but there are no such parameters, should I write them myself?

Comment: Are you using CMake GUI to look for them?

Comment: @arrowd     yes, i use cmake gui

Comment: Check the "Advanced" textbox to see `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable, then.